# Slideable SplitViews similar to the AutoScout24 App

Tags: objective-c, ipad, draggable, uisplitviewcontroller

i am try to reproduce the same function as in the AutoScout24 iPad App. I think its only a UIViewController with some special actions. I would add the other ViewControllers to the View from the RootViewController and handle the slide Effects with my own functions.

But is there a simpler way to do it? Like a completed solution on GitHub?

Would it be the best practice to do this on my own way? And am i right with my solution that i give at top of my post?

If you want to try the App out to see the how it works check it out here: http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/autoscout24-mobile-autosuche/id311785642?mt=8

Screnshots from AutoScout24[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at ViewDeck, it should give you the desired functionality:

https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

Answer (score 0):

I have used JTReveal for the same purpose and it worked great. have a look [here](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo).